# KineticJS: Efficient way to simulate scrolling on a fixed stage

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have a page that is laid out in a way that's very similar to how you might lay out a tournament bracket, with three panels, within a wrapper div with a set height..  The two green panels are standard HTML lists, with `overflow-y: scroll`, so that they can be scrolled up and down.  The white panel is the KineticJS Stage, and does not scroll.

Each horizontal blue line is "attached" to an LI in one of the lists.  As the user scrolls down a list, and the LIs move up (and potentially out of view), the horizontal lines need to "move" up with them, and the vertical blue lines need to do the same, to give the illusion that they are scrolling as well.  The red circle stays fixed in the center.

Now, based on my limited knowledge of HTML5 Canvases and KineticJS, it seems like I'm going to need to add a `.scroll()` event handler that adjusts the points on the lines, and redraws the layer.

My question is: is that the most efficient way to achieve this effect, and if not, how should I go about it?

[image: Crude Diagram]

Comment: The most efficient way is to try it out first, and optimize later.

Answer (score 0):

**Just do it just like all the games do.**

Create 2 "extra" Kinetic groups each containing a set of left-horizontal+left-vertical and right-horizontal+right-vertical lines.

Position the new groups "offstage" above and below the canvas (Let's call this the starting position).

[image]

As a new list item scrolls into view from the top/bottom, scroll the appropriate new group into view also.

After any list item scrolls off the screen, scroll that "extra" group offstage again.

Here's the key...When any "extra" group goes offstage you will set everything back to it starting position.

This creates the illusion of infinite bracket lines.